# Finding all local network broadcast addresses

Tags: .net, networking, udp, broadcast

I'm building a device discovery system using a UDP broadcast message. I started out using `UdpClient` and `IPAddress.Broadcast`.

The solution worked for clients on the local machine, but not other clients on the local network.

Via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290329/why-is-my-udp-broadcast-failing), I discovered that Win 7 blocks broadcast messages. When I manually entered the local network broadcast address it worked great. Now I want to write some code that will iterate through all of the local network adapters (something like `NetworkInterfaces.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`) and find the local network broadcast address for the network each adapter is connected to, if any.

Does this make sense? What's the best was to ping the local subnet that would be compatible with Win 7, IPv6, IPv4, etc. In other words, universally compatible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, something like...?

```
  foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (Interface.SupportsMulticast)
            {
                IPInterfaceProperties IPProperties = Interface.GetIPProperties();
                foreach (IPAddressInformation  address in IPProperties.MulticastAddresses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(address.Address);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this with the `NetworkInterface` class instead of WMI?